# Is it possible to run a single test in MiniTest?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, minitest

I can run all tests in a single file with:

```
rake test TEST=path/to/test_file.rb
```

However, if I want to run just one test in that file, how would I do it?

I'm looking for similar functionality to:

```
rspec path/to/test_file.rb -l 25
```

Comment: 8 years later and for rails 5+ users `rails test path/to/test_file.rb:25` see @Derek_Hill ans - taken from https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#the-rails-test-runner

Answer (score 45, accepted):

> I'm looking for similar functionality to rspec path/to/file.rb -l 25

With [Nick Quaranto's "m" gem](http://github.com/qrush/m), you can say:

```
m spec/my_spec.rb:25
```

Comment: While the answer works and was exactly what was asked :-) The Mini-test way of running a single test is by name matching (see Mr Grimm's answer). If you've tried this and rejected it then it's time to try the none-standard alternatives - such as Nick's Gem.

Comment: True, I agree. I actually wish m let you also pass in -n as an option... or that MiniTest just supported using line numbers as well as method names.

Comment: Heads up! `m` [currently doesn't work this Minitest 5.0](https://github.com/qrush/m/issues/35).

Comment: while this gem make things similar to rspec way of run a single test, Minitest has a built-in way to run a single test that was exactly the question. The dependency is not necessary. It is good to know that could be easier with an accessory gem (like may have many around) but I think that for this question, the pure minitest answers like from jduan or randomor would fit better

Comment: Passing filename and line number to the test runner is trivially easy to automate from your editor, specifying a test name is not.

Answer (score 241):

The command should be:

```
% rake test TEST=test/test_foobar.rb TESTOPTS="--name=test_foobar1 -v"
```

Comment: +1 - this is what you wanna do. If you want to test all the test in a specific file, just leave `TESTOPTS=...` away

Comment: Very usefull answer. I make MinitestReporter to show rerun commands of failed tests at the end of test report. See: https://gist.github.com/foton/141b9f73caccf13ccfcc

Comment: What does the `-v` do?

Answer (score 174):

Have you tried:

```
ruby path/to/test_file.rb --name test_method_name
```

Comment: What about for tests using Minispec, defined like `specify {}`? Those just show up as `test_0001_anonymous`... and there could be multiple `test_0001_anonymous`s if the same syntax is used in multiple describe blocks... any suggestions for running single tests in this kind of environment?

Comment: "tc" stands for "test case".

Comment: It says `cannot load such file -- test_helper`.

Comment: use  `ruby -Itest path/to/tc_file.rb --name test_method_name` like http://stackoverflow.com/a/15714985/327786

Comment: `bundle exec ruby -I lib path/to --name test_fit`

Answer (score 62):

No gem required:
`ruby -Itest test/lib/test.rb --name /some_test/`

Source: http://blog.arvidandersson.se/2012/03/28/minimalicous-testing-in-ruby-1-9

Answer (score 52):

This is one of the things that bother me about the `string name definition` in tests.

When you have:

```
def test_my_test
end
```

you always know how your test is named so you can execute it like this:

```
ruby my_test -n test_my_test
```

But when you have something like:

```
it "my test" do
end
```

you are never sure how this test is really named internally so you can not use the `-n` option just directly.

To know how this test is named internally you only have an option: execute the whole file to try to figure out looking in the logs.

My workaround is (temporally) add something to the test name very unique like:

```
it "my test xxx" do
end
```

and then use the *RegEx* version of the '-n' parameter like:

```
ruby my_test.rb -n /xxx/
```

Comment: regex version of -n parameter was the clutch piece of info, thanks!

Comment: Note that you can check this by calling `__method__` within the context of the currently executing method (your test, in this instance). The present implementation results in something like `"does not break my stuff".gsub(" ", "_").prepend("test_")`. Then run, for example, `ruby -Itest test/integration/stuff_flow_test.rb --name test_does_not_break_my_stuff`.

Answer (score 43):

If you are using MiniTest with Rails 5+ the best way to run all tests in a single file is:

```
bin/rails test path/to/test_file.rb
```

And for a single test (e.g. on line 25):

```
bin/rails test path/to/test_file.rb:25
```

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#the-rails-test-runner

Comment: FYI this is not working for me in rails 5.0.7. The command ends up running all the test in the file no matter what line number I enter.

Comment: I had the same issue. If you redefine the `:test` task it seems to cause issues with the rails runner.

Answer (score 25):

You can use this to run a single file:

```
rake test TEST=test/path/to/file.rb
```

I also used

```
ruby -I"lib:test" test/path/to/file.rb
```

for better display.

Answer (score 13):

You can pass `--name` to run a test by its name or a number within its name:

```
-n, --name PATTERN               Filter run on /regexp/ or string.
```

e.g.:

```
$ ruby spec/stories/foo_spec.rb --name 3

FAIL (0:00:00.022) test_0003_has foo
Expected: "foo"
Actual: nil
```

This flag is documented [in Minitest’s README](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest#running-your-tests).

Answer (score 12):

There are 2 ways to do it:

1. Run tests 'manually' (see Andrew Grimm's answer).
2. Hack `Rake::TestTask` target to use a different tests loader.

`Rake::TestTask` (from rake 0.8.7) theoretically is able to pass additional options to `MiniTest::Unit` with a `"TESTOPTS=blah-blah"` command line option, for example:

```
% rake test TEST=test/test_foobar.rb TESTOPTS="--name test_foobar1 -v"
```

In practice, the option `--name` (a filter for test names) won't work, due to rake internals. To fix that you'll need to write a small monkey patch in your Rakefile:

```
# overriding the default rake tests loader
class Rake::TestTask
  def rake_loader
    'test/my-minitest-loader.rb'
  end
end

# our usual test terget 
Rake::TestTask.new {|i|
  i.test_files = FileList['test/test_*.rb']
  i.verbose = true 
}
```

This patch requires you to create a file `test/my-minitest-loader.rb`:

```
ARGV.each { |f|
  break if f =~ /^-/
  load f
}
```

To print all possible options for Minitest, type

```
% ruby -r minitest/autorun -e '' -- --help
```

Comment: Note that the initial example does work correctly with a more recent `rake` (0.9.2) and no monkey patch is required.

Comment: When I tried with rake version 10.5.0 `TESTOPTS="--name test_foobar"` does not work, but `TESTOPTS="--name=test_foobar"` works.

Answer (score 3):

I am in Rails Version **4.2.11.3** and Ruby Version **2.4.7p357**

Below one worked for me.

```
ruby -Itest <relative_minitest_file_path> --name /<test_name>/
```

Answer (score 3):

Rails 7.1 [introduce](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/48807) new syntax for specific lines for tests

Now you can run not only specific tests by single line

```
bin/rails test test/models/user_test.rb:10 # by line 10
```

but also by lines range

```
bin/rails test test/models/user_test.rb:10-20 # by lines 10..20
```

or even by few ranges

```
bin/rails test test/models/user_test.rb:10-20:25-30 # by lines 10..20 and 25..30
```

Answer (score 2):

I use `ruby /path/to/test -n /distinguishable word/`

Edit:
`-n` is a shorthand for `--name`. `distinguishable word` can be any string you put in the test description, I usually use some random word that I know won't be present in other tests' descriptions.

Comment: Can you explain that further? What does that `-n` parameter mean?

Comment: It's a shorthand for `--name`. Just a convenience thing. Especially useful with the /regex/, I usually just put some random word into a test name (that I know won't be present in other tests' descriptions).

Comment: Please add some explanation about that to the answer itself, not to the comment section

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Turn gem with minitest, just make sure to use `Turn.config.pattern` option since Turn Minitest runner doesn't respect --name option in ARGs.

Comment: This was the hint I needed to realize that Turn is what was swallowing the `name` option. Thanks! Being that Turn is no longer being maintained, I plan to migrate to minitest-reporters

Answer (score 1):

> I'm looking for similar functionality to:
>
> rspec path/to/test_file.rb -l 25

There is a gem that does exactly that: `minitest-line`.

```
gem install minitest-line
ruby test/my_file -l 5
```

from https://github.com/judofyr/minitest-line#minitest-line

Comment: Hi @ChrisHough, could you describe what exactly isn't working (e.g. an error message)? The minitest-line gem's purpose is solely to run a single test in MiniTest. If it's not working you might have found a bug in minitest-line.

Answer (score 1):

Following will work

```
def test_abc
end

test "hello world"
end
```

This can run by

```
bundle exec ruby -I test path/to/test -n test_abc

bundle exec ruby -I test path/to/test -n test_hello_word
```

Answer (score 0):

Install gem [minitest-focus](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest-focus) and use the keyword focus on test/spec like below to run only the specific test.

```
focus
def test
end


focus
it "test" do
end
```

This would not need any command line argument to be passed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [`Minitest::TestTask`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017158/running-ruby-unit-tests-with-rake/77506728#77506728) and no Rails, you can also pass the name of a test using the `N` environment variable:

`rake test N=test_some_test_name`