# How to run multiple Minitest files simultaneously from the terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, command-line-interface, minitest

I currently have three ruby files containing tests written with Minitest, and I'd like to run them all at once but I've not had much luck. If I was using RSpec, I'd just do `rspec spec/*` and all the different tests would run as if from one big test file.

**Things I've tried:**

- `ruby test/game_test.rb test/board_test.rb test/player_test.rb`
- `ruby test/*`

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It's likely one of the answers here can be worked a little bit to accomplish your task: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285711/is-it-possible-to-run-a-single-test-in-minitest

Comment: Oh, thanks. it seems I have to learn what Rake is and how to use it.

Comment: ^ this approach is described by the docs: https://github.com/minitest/minitest#rake-tasks-

Comment: Thank you so much Jake. I was able to get it to work using the instructions in the link you sent. I wish there were more beginner friendly guides out there on using Rake. (maybe I just don't know where to look).